# Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ in $A:= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : | z - z_0 | \gt |z_0 + i|, Im(z_0) \gt 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent expansion of $f(z) := \dfrac{1}{1+z^2}$ in the set $A:= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : | z - z_0 | \gt |z_0 + i|, Im(z_0) \gt 0\}$. I've drawn a picture of this:

[image]

I know that if $r \lt R$ and $f \in \mathcal{O}\left(K_{r,R}(z_0)\right)$, where $K_{r,R}(z_0) = \{z \in \mathbb{C}:r <|z-z_0| < R \}$, then one can find two functions $f_N(z) \in \mathcal{O}\left(B_R(z_0)\right) \text{ and } f_H \in \mathcal{O} \left(\mathbb{C} \backslash \overline{B_r(z_0)}\right)$ such that

$$f(z) = f_N (z) + f_H(z) \quad \forall z \in K_{r,R} (z_0)$$

In my case I've chosen $r:= |z_0+i|$ and $R = \infty$. To evaluate the Laurent expansion I've decomposed $f(z)$ in this way:

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1+z^2} = \dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{ (z-i)} - \dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{(z+i)}$$

Now i noticed that:

• $\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{ (z-i)} - \dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{(z+i)} \notin \mathcal{O}\left(B_R(z_0)\right)$

• $\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{ (z-i)} \notin \mathcal{O}\left(B_R(z_0)\right)$

• $- \dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{(z+i)} \notin \mathcal{O}\left(B_R(z_0)\right)$

Hence *edit: there are some functions for which the secondary expansion $f_N(z) \equiv 0$* I've then tried to expand the function with the help of the geometric series, like I've seen in an example in the lecture:

$$- \dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{(z+i)} = \dfrac{-1}{2i} \dfrac{1}{z-z_0} \dfrac{1}{1+ \frac{z_0+i}{z-z_0}} \qquad (1)$$

Now we see from the picture that $\mid \frac{z_0+i}{z-z_0} \mid < 1 \quad \forall z \in A$

$$(1) = \dfrac{-1}{2i} \dfrac{1}{z-z_0} \sum_{\nu \ge 0} (-1)^{\nu}\left(\dfrac{z_0 + i}{z-z_0}\right)^{\nu} = \dfrac{-1}{2i} \sum_{\nu \ge 0} \dfrac{(-1)^{\nu}\left(z_0 + i\right)^{\nu}}{\left(z-z_0\right)^{\nu +1}}$$

The same for the other part:

$$\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{(z-i)} = \dfrac{1}{2i} \dfrac{1}{z-z_0} \dfrac{1}{1- \frac{i-z_0}{z-z_0}} \qquad (2)$$

Since $\mid \frac{i-z_0}{z-z_0} \mid \lt 1 \quad \forall z \in A$

$$(2) = \dfrac{1}{2i} \sum_{\nu \ge 0} \dfrac{\left(i-z_0\right)^{\nu}}{\left(z-z_0\right)^{\nu + 1}}$$

hence the Laurent expansion in $K_{r,\infty}(z_0)$ is

$$f_H(z) = \dfrac{1}{2i} \sum_{\nu \ge 0} \dfrac{\left(i-z_0\right)^{\nu}}{\left(z-z_0\right)^{\nu + 1}} + \dfrac{-1}{2i} \sum_{\nu \ge 0} \dfrac{(-1)^{\nu}\left(z_0 + i\right)^{\nu}}{\left(z-z_0\right)^{\nu +1}}$$

$$ edit: f(z) = \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{\left((i-z_0)^\nu + (-1)^{\nu+1}(i+z_0)^\nu\right)}{(z-z_0)^{(\nu+1)}}.$$

Is this right? I'm not very sure about the choice of $R = \infty$ and the fact that $f_N(z) \equiv 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: Yes, it's correct. Good work.

With one caveat: if $z_0 = i$, your expansion of $(2)$ is unnecessarily complicated, it's plain $\frac{1}{2i} \frac{1}{z-i}$ then. *But*, writing it as a series with infinitely many terms (all but the first of which turn out to be $0$) keeps the development uniform (no special case for $z_0 = i$), and is therefore good. It may, however, be good to say a word about that (a parenthetical remark à la "for uniformity of the exposition, no special treatment of $z_0 = i$"). But it's not necessary to add such a remark.

A Laurent expansion is always valid for the largest annulus not containing any singularity of the function, and since $f$ has only the two poles at $i$ and $-i$ as singularities, a Laurent expansion valid in any point $z$ with $\lvert z-z_0\rvert > \lvert z_0+i\rvert$ automatically holds on the whole complement of the disk $\{z : \lvert z-z_0\rvert \leqslant \lvert z_0+i\rvert\}$, so you don't "choose" $R=\infty$, that drops out automatically.

A minor cosmetic point: it is desirable to write the representation of $f$ as a single series, combining the two parts into one,

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \left((i-z_0)^\nu + (-1)^{\nu+1}(i+z_0)^\nu\right)(z-z_0)^{-(\nu+1)}.$$

One point that I found irritating was

> Now I noticed that [some functions are not in $\mathcal{O}(B_R(z_0))$]. Hence $f_N(z) \equiv 0$.

That conclusion is valid because of the special type of the functions involved here, but in general, a function has nontrivial primary and secondary parts. Here, you have two functions of the form $(z-a)^k$ (times a constant), and such functions always contribute only to either the principal or the secondary part, not to both. But composite functions generally contribute to both parts.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the thorough answer, and also for pointing out that normally $f_N(z)$ is non-trivial (I've edited this). You really helped me understanding a lot of things, I also didn't know that the Laurent expansion is always valid for the largest annulus not containing any singularity of the function, and this helps me solving the next exercise. Thank you very much!